# Roslaunch cannot find launch file

Tags: ros, roslaunch, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed uvc_camera package by running:

```
~/ros_catkin_ws/src $ git clone git://github.com/ktossell/camera_umd.git 
~/ros_catkin_ws $ catkin_make_isolated --pkg camera_umd --install
```

Everything went fine, no errors.
But when I'm trying to launch a launch file from this package it says it cannot find it:

```
~/ros_catkin_ws $ ls /dev/video*
/dev/video0  /dev/video1
~/ros_catkin_ws $ roslaunch uvc_camera stereo_node.launch
[stereo_node.launch] is neither a launch file in package [uvc_camera] nor is [uvc_camera] a launch file name
```

The stereo_node.launch is still in the src folder:

```
~/ros_catkin_ws $ sudo find / -name stereo_node.launch
~/ros_catkin_ws/src/camera_umd/uvc_camera/launch/stereo_node.launch
```

Is it normal that after installation the .launch file is still in the /src folder? If no, then would this be an installation issue? If yes, then why roslaunch cannot find it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134751/roslaunch-cannot-find-launch-file/) by [evk02](https://answers.ros.org/users/11636/evk02/) on ROS Answers with karma: 218 on 2014-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like an installation problem; the camera_umd package probably isn't installing that launch file.

I would inspect the package's CMakeLists.txt to be sure, and then file a bug against that package.

**EDIT**: confirmed, this CMakeLists.txt doesn't have install rules for any of the launch files: https://github.com/ktossell/camera_umd/blob/master/uvc_camera/CMakeLists.txt

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [evk02](https://answers.ros.org/users/11636/evk02/) on 2014-03-02**:
Thanks, I filed the bug.
Do you know where can I manually place the .launch files for to find it until the CMakeLists.txt's bug doesn't get resolved?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-02**:
You can manually install them to ~/ros_catkin_ws/install/share/camera_umd/ . You may have to create the directory if it doesn't exist.

**Comment by [evk02](https://answers.ros.org/users/11636/evk02/) on 2014-03-03**:
Thanks, I have copied the launch file to ~/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/uvc_camera/ and now it works.
Thanks!